# Legal hold for file servers

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-sharing

I am to build a new file server with Windows Server 2012R2. The edict being passed my way is basically to have the entire common share on legal hold, so as to retain all file changes. Is throwing a bunch of space to VSS the only way to do this? Or does 2012R2 have a better way to address the order of "keep everything"?

Comment: Sharepoint might be more of value for that, to keep version history of each file, else it's daily backup that you keep ...

Comment: I was hoping not to go the Sharepoint route, given the data size and that we didn't want to have to do any naming gymnastics (i.e., point the file server name to the SP server). Also, the idea is that we simply backup the server on a weekly rotation with NO history, as keeping a file vault or legal hold means you keep everything - the history is in the files kept.

Comment: Maybe that is a good tip too (svn/subversion for a file store); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662748/does-subversion-support-word-excel-powerpoint-docs